Secure Random Seed Not Working In MainActivity
I am trying to get the same keys every time I run my app - this is so I can easily debug and have the same output for my functions every time I run.
I am getting a super weird problem though, where in my unit tests, this works as expected and returns the same public key every time. However, if I run the exact same code from my main application, it generates a different code every time.
GenerateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeys
package com.test.tomtestplayground

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.ECNamedCurveTable
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec

class GenerateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeys {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
    @Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException::class)
    fun generate(): String {
        // Fixed seed for SecureRandom to generate the same key pair every time
        val secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
        secureRandom.setSeed("test-seed".toByteArray())
        val keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC")
        keyGen.initialize(ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"), secureRandom)
        val pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair()
        val publicKey = pair.public as ECPublicKey
        val privateKey = pair.private

        val x: ByteArray = publicKey.getW().getAffineX().toByteArray()
        val y: ByteArray = publicKey.getW().getAffineY().toByteArray()

        val xbi = BigInteger(1, x)
        val ybi = BigInteger(1, y)
        val x9 = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName("secp256r1")
        val curve = x9.curve
        val point = curve.createPoint(xbi, ybi)

        val publicKeyByteArray = point.getEncoded(true)

        return publicKeyByteArray.toHexString()
    }
}

GenerateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeysTest
This works as expected and passes every time
package com.test.tomtestplayground

import android.nfc.Tag
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep
import io.mockk.*
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner
import java.security.Security

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class GenerateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeysTest {

    private val generateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeys = GenerateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeys()


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldReturnSameKeyEveryTime() {
        val publicKeyCompressed = generateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeys.generate()
        assertEquals(publicKeyCompressed, "032f0ca7da7eb706c7de924e534bcb76e36a471ed2ea0c99b2ad59e70394d83bf6")
    }


}

MainActivity
This logs a different key every single time - which is wrong.
package com.test.tomtestplayground

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.passentry.tomtestplayground.ui.theme.TomTestPlaygroundTheme
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import java.security.Security

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())

        Log.d("MainActivity", GenerateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeys().generate())
        setContent {
            TomTestPlaygroundTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    TomTestPlaygroundTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

Build.gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.passentry.tomtestplayground"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.passentry.tomtestplayground"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.68")

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)


    testImplementation("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.11.1")
    testImplementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68")  // Added BouncyCastle provider
    testImplementation("org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.68")  // Added BouncyCastle PKIX
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.12.0")

}


SecureRandom does not rely solely on a user supplied seed. It's going to generate new random values regardless of the seed you supply. If you need repeatability use regular Random.

Or apply a dedicated key derivation function like PBKDF2 instead of a random number generator. A key derivation function guarantees reproducibility.

@Topaco Im having the same issue with PBKDF2 aswell. It generates a different one each time i run the activity, but the same in tests

@ElliottFrisch thanks but I'm not sure how to do this. KeyGen requires SecureRandom

Then you are doing something wrong. Without code one can't tell what it is exactly. Post an MCVE, that contains only the relevant logic.

Thanks @Topaco, this works now.
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECDomainParameters
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPrivateKeyParameters
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.FixedPointCombMultiplier
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec

class GenerateTerminalEphemeralPublicPrivateKeys {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
    @Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException::class)
    fun generate(): String {
        // Derive key from a fixed seed using PBKDF2
        val seed = "test-seed"
        val salt = ByteArray(16) { 0 } // fixed salt for deterministic output
        val iterations = 10000
        val keyLength = 256
        val keySpec = PBEKeySpec(seed.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, keyLength)
        val secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
        val derivedKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).encoded

        // Convert derived key to BigInteger
        val privateKeyD = BigInteger(1, derivedKey.sliceArray(0 until 32))

        // Use the derived private key to generate the public key
        val x9 = CustomNamedCurves.getByName("secp256r1")
        val curve = x9.curve
        val domainParams = ECDomainParameters(curve, x9.g, x9.n, x9.h)
        val privateKeyParams = ECPrivateKeyParameters(privateKeyD, domainParams)
        val publicKeyParams = ECPublicKeyParameters(
            FixedPointCombMultiplier().multiply(domainParams.g, privateKeyD),
            domainParams
        )

        val publicKeyByteArray = publicKeyParams.q.getEncoded(true)

        return publicKeyByteArray.toHexString()
    }

    private fun ByteArray.toHexString(): String {
        return joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
    }
}

